# event not selecting single select2 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, codepen

I have a form with two select statements, one a multi select and a single select both using select2.  The need to get the value of the last selected item so I can make an ajax call to populate the other form.  I have created a simple example that is almost straight out of their documentation, and it does not work.  See here https://codepen.io/riskiii/pen/ZxjLJY

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form class="signup-form-container" method="post" id="roles-form" name="roles-form">
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
</form>

// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});

$(".js-example-basic-single").on("select2:select", function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  console.log(data);
  alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: Should you use select2? Check this out http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=a271c4613c07dfe1054745c47d1d5e9f

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, also added some checking if nothing was selected. Helps to reset your other `select` if need be.

```js
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
  $(".js-example-basic-single").on("change", function(e) {
    var data = $(this).val();
    if (data == 0) {
    alert("nothing selected");
    } else {
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<form class="signup-form-container" method="post" id="roles-form" name="roles-form">
  <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="0">pick one</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I had added jQuery in the pen but forgot to put it in the post.